# PermissionError: How to read a file from a remote file server (accessible by IP) with authentication?

Tags: python

How can I read a file from a remote file server (accessible by IP) using Python3? How to set the user and password with this IP file server setup?

Example of file location (with authentication needed): \\10.123.123.132\example.jpg

The function I tried is as below which is throwing a PermissionError error. I am using django as a web framework. When the file server access is pre-authenticated via Windows authentication (manually) and django project is run locally on localhost, the code works fine. However, when the django project is served using winsw and waitress (https://github.com/winsw/winsw, https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/runner.html), the file server access code fails to work with PermissionError logged.

```
def copy_file(fullname, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
        data_file = open(fullname, "rb")
        output.write(data_file.read())
        output.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\app\services.py", line 21, in copy_file
    data_file = open(fullname, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\10.123.123.132\\example.jpg'
```

Will appreciate any feedback and clue, thank you very much.

Comment: By default, services run as a special system user that does not have permission for your file shares.  Have you set the username for your service?  By the way, you can use `import shutil` / `shutil.copyfile(src,dst)` to copy files by name.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the tip in copying the file with shutil. I will try that. As for setting the username for the service, how is that done?

Comment: In the services control panel.  Run `services.msc` to bring up the control panel, find your service, and edit its parameters.

Comment: Hello @TimRoberts, thank you very much for your answer, it worked! If you can transfer your comment as Answer, I will mark it as an answer to this post! In my end, adding the login username and password to the service parameters was not enough. I had to also add my remote file server credentials in 'Credential Manager' > 'Windows Credentials' before it totally worked. Still thanks for being awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, services run as a special system user that does not have permission for your file shares. Have you set the username for your service?

You can set the user name in the services control panel. Run `services.msc` to bring up the control panel, find your service, and edit its parameters.

By the way, you can use `import shutil` / `shutil.copyfile(src,dst)` to copy files by name.